# Why is trim() not working inside map in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

```
user=> (.trim "   kkk   ")
"kkk"
user=> (map .trim ["jjj " "  llll" " o "] )

CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: .trim in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:1)
```

Any explanation for this behavior ?

I ended up using clojure.string/trim. but wanted to know, whats the prob here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to wrap `.trim` in an anonymous function so `map` gets a first-class function instead of a member function:

```
(map #(.trim %) ["jjj " "  llll" " o "])
```

Alternatively, you could use [memfn](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/memfn) to create this first-class function for you:

```
(map (memfn trim) ["jjj " "  llll" " o "])
```

Comment: memfn was deprecated in If I recall 1.0 or 1.1. It was added to Clojure before the anonymous function syntax #() existed

Answer (score 4):

This works:

```
(map #(.trim %) ["jjj " "  llll" " o "] )
```

So I guess `.trim` is some sort syntactic sugar that doesn't have a meaning outside forms?

Comment: `(.trim "jj ")` is syntactic sugar for `(. "jjj " trim)`. See [The '.' special form](http://clojure.org/java_interop#dot)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a member function like that. It's not a Clojure function. Easiest way is to use a closure.

```
(map #(.trim %) ["  aa " "  bb "])
```

You can also convert a member function to a Clojure function with memfn.